# MapStateToProps Returning Null in react-redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to learn redux. I have successfully implemented mapDispatchedToProps. But mapStateToProps function is returning Null. My code is given below.

**MeatShopReducer**

```
const initial_state = {
  beefs: 20,
  muttons: 30,
  chickens: 40
};

const MeatShopReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_BEEF":
      console.log("action dispatched");
      var new_state = { ...state };
      new_state.beefs = new_state.beefs - 1;
      console.log(new_state);
      //return new_state;
      return new_state;

    default:
      console.log("default:");
      console.log(state);
      return state;
  }
};

export default MeatShopReducer;
```

**MeatShop.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
class MeatShop extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("render fired");
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Meat Shop Redux</div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Unit</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Beef</td>
              <td>{this.state.beef}</td>
              <td>{this.state.beef}</td>
              <td>
                <button onClick={this.props.ADD_BEEF}>Add</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mutton</td>
              <td>{this.state.mutton}</td>
              <td>{this.state.mutton}</td>
              <td>
                <button>Add</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Chicken</td>
              <td>{this.state.chicken}</td>
              <td>{this.state.chicken}</td>
              <td>
                <button>Add</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    ADD_BEEF: () => dispatch({ type: "ADD_BEEF" })
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    beef: state.beefs,
    mutton: state.muttons,
    chicken: state.chickens
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MeatShop);
```

My Understanding so far:
I commented out the lines in render function where i need to extract value from state. Then i dispatched the action. console.log from the action shows the store is updated.From this i came to decision that store is connected to MyShop.js correctly and also my MapDispatchToAction is also working.

But when i try to extract value from this.state, It gives me null. So mapStateToProps is not working. I am not finding any mistakes in my reducer. I have  also included a default case in my reducer. So it should not fail in initialization phase i guess.

Comment: (sidenote) you can use `var new_state = { ...state, beefs: state.beefs-1 };` to avoid mutation.

Comment: @jcal ..thanks for the suggestion .. can you give me some good study material on updating the store while avoiding mutation. As i am new i am finding it hard to understand redux.

Comment: this whole _no mutation_ thingy comes from the functional programming paradigm (fp). searching for articles about fp in javascript. this could improve your understanding about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connect()` is a HOC that passes a piece of global state into your component via props. So the local state of your component doesn't have any data.

So instead of calling, for example, `this.state.beef` try `this.props.beef`. It should work fine.

Comment: thanks man.. this worked like a charm ... I was following a video tutorial in youtube.. that guy just forgot to show this part

Answer (score 0):

While mapping your state to props (via your `mapStateToProps` function) you're actually providing props to your connected component. You don't use local state in your component.

So you can access your data as:

```
console.log(this.props.beef);
console.log(this.props.mutton);
console.log(this.props.chicken);
```